# Свойство зависимости из UserControl в MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf

Не работает свойство зависимости

UserControl.cs:

```
    // private double Radius = 100;
    private void DrawScale()
    {
        double bigTick = 9;
        for (double i = 0; i <= 90; i = i + bigTick)
        {
            Point p = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle
            {
                Height = 5,
                Width = 15,
                Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua),
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                RenderTransformOrigin = p
            };

            TransformGroup trGp = new TransformGroup();
            RotateTransform rTr = new RotateTransform();
            double iRadian = (i * Math.PI) / 180;
            rTr.Angle = i;
            trGp.Children.Add(rTr);
            TranslateTransform tTr = new TranslateTransform();
            tTr.X = (int) ((Radius) * Math.Cos(iRadian));
            tTr.Y = (int) ((Radius) * Math.Sin(iRadian));
            trGp.Children.Add(tTr);
            r.RenderTransform = trGp;
            gr.Children.Add(r);
        }
    }

    public double Radius
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Radius", typeof(double), typeof(RoundScale), null);
```

userControl.xaml

```
  <Grid x:Name="gr"/>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
 <Grid>
    <local:RoundScale Radius="90" />
 </Grid>
```

Если переменную Radius в UserControl.cs разкомментировать и удалить из кода свойство зависимости то все работает как надо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неправильно определили dependency property. CLR-свойство должно называться так, как ваше dependency property, минус суффикс `Property`. В вашем случае dependency property называется `MyPropertyProperty`, а CLR-свойство — `Radius`.

Переименуйте dependency property в `RadiusProperty`.

---

Документация: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/custom-dependency-properties#checklist-for-defining-a-dependency-property:

> When you create the identifier field, name this field by the name of the property as you registered it, plus the suffix `Property`.

---

Ещё одна проблема — опрос dependency property из конструктора. Дело в том, что значение dependency property, заданное непосредственно в XAML, устанавливается в `InitializeComponent`, а привязки могут сработать ещё позже. Поэтому имеет смысл либо читать значение на событии `Loaded`, либо подписаться на изменения.

---

Если вам нужно подписаться на изменения, проще всего указать callback в определении dependency property:

```
public double Radius
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(RadiusProperty); }
    set { SetValue(RadiusProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Radius", typeof(double), typeof(RoundScale),
        new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnRadiusChangedStatic));

static void OnRadiusChangedStatic(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) =>
    ((RoundScale)d).OnRadiusChanged();

void OnRadiusChanged()
{
    // тут у вас поменялся радиус, реагируйте
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь но все равно не работает

Comment: @XmaksasX: Значит, есть ещё какая-то ошибка. А ваш класс, в котором лежит dependency property, называется `RoundScale` или нет?

Comment: Да имя класса RoundScale

Comment: @XmaksasX: Хм. А почему в вашем примере не `<local:RoundScale Radius="90"/>`, а `<local:UserControl2 Radius="90" />`?

Comment: Извините поправил

Comment: @XmaksasX: Окей, это уже лучше. Тогда вопрос -- что значит "не работает"? Чему равно значение `Radius` в функции `DrawScale`? И откуда вы вызываете функцию -- не из конструктора ли?

Comment: Не работает не меняется радиус при изменении свойства в MainWindow, вызываю из конструктора

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь вызвал функцию не из конструктора а из события RoundScale_Loaded и все за работало

Comment: Отметил но решили проблему ответы в комментариях. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Все таки проблема не решена, значение Radius меняется только один раз при загрузке, динамически изменить не получается

Comment: @XmaksasX: А вы перечитываете его, или только один раз на Loaded?

Comment: Только один раз на Loaded, я так понимаю нужно зарегистрировать PropertyChangedCallback, но пока не получается

Comment: @XmaksasX: Дополнил ответ, смотрите.

Comment: Спасибо это я сделал, выходит что при обновлении Radius надо чистить Grid и заново вызывать функцию DrawScale?

Comment: @XmaksasX: Ну это уж я не знаю, тут вам виднее. Попробуйте! Может быть, можно просто у уже созданных объектов поменять свойства.