# Привязка к динамически созданному объекту

Tags: c#, wpf

Как организовать привязку между динамически созданным объектом и объектом на форме

UserControl1.cs

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Label l = new Label
        {
            Content = MyProperty,
            Height = 40,
            Width = 30
        };
        RootGrid.Children.Add(l);
    }
}
```

UserControl1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded">
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid">

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1" x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <local:UserControl1 x:Name="Us" Height="34" Width="139" MyProperty="{Binding Value, ElementName=Sl}"/>
    <Slider x:Name="Sl" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310" SmallChange="1"/>
</Grid>
```

MyProperty принимает данные от Slider но только один раз во время загрузки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то под динамически создаваемым объектом вы понимаете это:

```
Label l = new Label
{
    Content = MyProperty,
    Height = 40,
    Width = 30
};
```

Здесь нет привязки, вместо этого вы просто задаёте значение свойству Content.
Необходимо описать связывание точно так же, как вы делаете это в XAML:

```
Label l = new Label
{
    Content = MyProperty,
    Height = 40,
    Width = 30
};

Binding b = new Binding()
{
    Source = this,
    Path = new PropertyPath("MyProperty"),
    Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
};

l.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, b);
```

Comment: Да привязки у меня в этом и был вопрос, сейчас попробую спасибо за помощь

Comment: Вот с эти примером все работает, а с моей задачей не работает

Comment: Вот ранее я задавал вопрос но задал не верно и задачу не решил, вот ссылка на пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/771591/%d0%a1%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-usercontrol-%d0%b2-mainwindow

Comment: @XmaksasX судя по вашим комментариям, задачу вы решили, и у вас всё заработало.

Comment: Да только я проверил не правильно поэтому и решил задать вопрос более правильно в этом посте

Comment: @XmaksasX видимо, забыли что-то ещё? :)

Comment: видимо да только не могу понять что(